# Reverse Proxy Behavior in a K8s Cluster for SSH Calls

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, iptables, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am building an application over a managed K8s cluster. I can create deployments & co with NodePort. Services are then accessible via these ports.

Managing all the exposed services and their ports is becoming a challenge and for the HTTP traffic, I was thinking of exposing a single nginx proxy that would proxy `https://someservice.someurl:someport` to  `https://someservice:someport` and have `someurl` DNS mapped to my front-end Ubuntu IP as depicted below.

[image]

For the web traffic, I reckon that it should work as expected. However, I have some deployments that are accessible via ssh;  git daemon for example. With these demons I am currently doing commands like this `git clone ssh://git@someipsofthecluster:someport/git-server/repos/somerepos` and I'd like to use the same DNS name as for http traffic (i.e. `git clone ssh://git@someservice.someurl:someport/git-server/repos/somerepo)`

I know about iptables where I can redirect traffic incoming from one port to another IP/port but I don't know how I would go about redirecting to a given machine/port with regards to the subdomain used.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to re-think how to do this as TCP load balancing or proxying based on DNS name is not really possible. More on this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/643131/proxying-tcp-by-hostname). Keep in mind that HTTP is a Layer 7 protocol so the proxy can use the 'Host' header to direct requests.

Filtering based on hostname is also not possible with iptables. More on that [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/482221/how-do-i-filter-incoming-connections-based-on-server-hostname-port-using-iptable).

You can, however, use a Layer 4 proxy, meaning a TCP proxy but this will be based on listening on a specific TCP port. [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/) can do it or you can also use something else like [Haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/).